# Using cublasStbsv in CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda, cublas

I'm trying to solve an equation with `cublasStbsv` function in my CUDA kernel. The kernel code is as follows:

```
__global__ void invokeDeviceCublasSgemm(cublasStatus_t *returnValue,
                                        int n,
                                        const float *d_alpha,
                                        const float *d_A,
                                        const float *d_B,
                                        const float *d_beta,
                                        float *d_C)
{
    cublasHandle_t cnpHandle;
    cublasStatus_t status = cublasCreate(&cnpHandle);

    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        *returnValue = status;
        return;
    }

//    /* Perform operation using cublas */
//    status =
//        cublasSgemm(cnpHandle,
//                    CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N,
//                    n, n, n,
//                    d_alpha,
//                    d_A, n,
//                    d_B, n,
//                    d_beta,
//                    d_C, n);

    float d_AA[5*5];
    float d_BB[5];
//    float d_X[5];

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
            {
                d_AA[i*5+j] = i;
            }else
            {
                d_AA[i*5+j] = 0;
            }

        }
        d_BB[i] = i*i;
    }

    status = cublasStbsv(cnpHandle,
                         CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_UPPER,
                         CUBLAS_OP_N,
                         CUBLAS_DIAG_NON_UNIT,
                         n,n,
                         d_AA,
                         5,
                         d_BB,
                         1);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
           printf("B i %d %f \n",i,d_BB[i]);
    }

    cublasDestroy(cnpHandle);

    *returnValue = status;
}
```

I don't understand why am I get the following error:

> Starting /home/xavier/Bureau/Developpement/Cuda/build-Cuda_CUBLAS-Qt_5_6_0_gcc_64-Release/Cuda_CUBLAS...
>
> simpleDevLibCUBLAS test running...
> GPU Device 0: "GeForce GTX 750 Ti" with compute capability 5.0
>
> Host and device APIs will be tested.
> ** On entry to SBSV  parameter number 7 had an illegal value
> B i 0 0.000000
> B i 1 1.000000
> B i 2 4.000000
> B i 3 9.000000
> B i 4 16.000000
> !!!! CUBLAS Device API call failed with code 7

I don't understand which function am I supposed to use to solve my linear equation - `cublasStpsv` or `cublasStrs`. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tbsp()` expects a triangular banded matrix; `tpsv()` expects a triangular matrix stored in packed format; and `trsv()` expects a dense matrix and only the upper/lower part will be used.

According to your code, I think you need `trsv()`.

Comment: What function should I use to solve linear equation with for example A = m*n  B = m*1  and X = m*1 . In trsv(), A had to be square I think?

Comment: @user3262532 Those 3 APIs are mathematically identical to each other - all require a square matrix, only the data storage schemes of A are different. If m>n, it's a linear least square fit problem - it's a math problem not a programming problem.

Comment: How can you do it when you have more equation that unknowed in your equation? Is there a function who solve A X = 0 with A not square?

Comment: @user3262532 for linear least square fitting, you could use SVD decomposition method, QR decomposition method or by solving `(A^T*A) * X = A^T*B`.  This link shows how to do it with QR decomposition. http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#ormqr-example1

Comment: Is it possible with cuda to solve A X =  B  in a cuda kernel?with A à full square matrix.   As I know it is not possible to use cusparse and cusolve on kernel.

Comment: @user3262532 Yes if you can do LU factorization with your own code and call trsv() twice. BTW I think we should focus only on your question above in the comment area.